# Event called when selecting a video with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, events, uiimagepickercontroller

When selecting a video with UIImagePickerController, it directly goes to a page showing the video and allowing me to play it. What event is called at the moment this page is displayed ?

It's not the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` event because this one is called after I click on choose on this last page.

I would like to add my own controls on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `UIImagePickerController` precludes you from changing the appearance of the album, as outlined by [Apple here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller).

> Important
>
> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This
>   class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.
>   **The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified**,
>   with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the
>   cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional
>   information or manage the interactions between the camera interface
>   and your code.

Emphasis mine. The exception does not apply in your case, since that is for the camera.

A solution for this then would be to create your own picker, for which there are plenty of articles and questions that outline the various items needed to do so.